# dynamic show/hide of div elements using id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("input[name$='type']").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value == 'variant-3'){
        $('[id*=variant]').show();
    }
    else{
         $('[id*=variant]').hide();
         $('.'+ value ).show();
    }
}).click();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/h6Q38/1/

Uses a class to show/hide the div elements. How can same be achieved using an id instead of a class? I tried, but I end up hiding all or showing all.

This is my code
http://jsfiddle.net/h6Q38/8/

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this :

```
<div id="variant-1">Variant 1</div>
<div id="variant-2">Variant 2</div>
<div id="variant-1.1">Variant 1.1</div>     <!-- don't reuse id! -->
<div id="variant-2.1">Variant 2.1</div>     <!-- don't reuse id! -->

$("input[name$='type']").click(function() {
    if (this.value=='variant-3'){
        $('[id^=variant]').show();
    } else{
        $('[id^=variant]').hide();
        $('[id^='+this.value+']').show();
    }        
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/rwH34/)

Comment: @FAngel You're totally right... I missed this requirement... The value conventions are awful here.

Comment: @FAngel and answer owner i made this another fiddle.. now it will be more clearer.. but it is not working.. jsfiddle.net/h6Q38/11

Comment: @dystroy i get that point you mentioned and used that but this new fiddle i tried that but dont know why is not working? http://jsfiddle.net/h6Q38/14/

Comment: @user2057047 in your fiddle, you have `$('#'+ value ).show();` which is actually `document.getElementById`, and that function always return only one element (ID must be unique, even if multiple uses of same ID will not throw an error). At the same time `$('[id^='+this.value+']').show();` will not use that function. But because of that it will be slower.

Comment: @FAngel quickly learning what was told i removed id's and added class instead and on comparison with class now still it is not working as required.. plz chk this http://jsfiddle.net/h6Q38/11/

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<p class="text1">Variants
 <label>
   <input type="radio" name="type" value="variant-1" id="type_0" checked="checked" />
   Variant 1</label>
 <label>
   <input type="radio" name="type" value="variant-2" id="type_1" />
   Variant 2</label>
    <label>
   <input type="radio" name="type" value="variant-3" id="type_2" />
   Show All</label>
</p>

<div class="variant-1">Variant 1</div>    
<div class="variant-2">Variant 2</div>    
<div class="variant-1">Variant 1.1</div>    
<div class="variant-2">Variant 2.1</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name$='type']").click(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(value == 'variant-3'){
            $('[class*=variant]').show();
        }
        else{
             $('[class*=variant]').hide();
             $('.'+ value ).show();
        }
    }).click();
});
```

**UPD**:

Here is updated demo, taking into account that ID can't be used more than once on a page:
http://jsfiddle.net/h6Q38/14/. Code is updated

Change all IDs to class. ID must be used only once on a page, so use classes instead. Above code is fixed to work with that.

Comment: it is now showing only Variant 1 or Variant 2 but not Variant 1.1 or Variant 2.1 http://jsfiddle.net/h6Q38/11/

Comment: @user2057047 see updated demo and answer. Remember that you should never use same ID more than once on a page.

Answer (score 0):

Change . in #? `$('#'+ value ).show();` :-p Otherwise i don't really see what's going on here to be honest. The value as classname is kinda sketchy but sure...

Comment: if you can't see what's going on, _ask clarifying questions in the comments_.

Comment: @Alnitak and answer owner i made thisd another fiddle.. now it will be more clearer.. but it is not working.. http://jsfiddle.net/h6Q38/11/

Answer (score 0):

One thing is what guys already pointed out - you have not changed `$('.'+ value )` to `$('#'+ value )`. But there is another problem. In your version with ids you have simply changed `class` attribute to `id` attribute, so you have 2 elements with the same `id` and that's an error. `id` attribute have to be unique.

If you want to use ids you should change them to be unique. If some elements should be connected somehow, you can add something to the end of `id`, like that for example:

```
<div id="variant-1">Variant 1</div>

<div id="variant-2">Variant 2</div>

<div id="variant-1-1">Variant 1.1</div>

<div id="variant-2-1">Variant 2.1</div>
```

And then update line that shows specific elements:

```
$('[id*='+ value + ']' ).show();
```

Check updated code - http://jsfiddle.net/h6Q38/8/

Comment: if id has to be unique then i shall use same values instead?? u see this fiddle you understand what i want to say.. http://jsfiddle.net/h6Q38/14/

Comment: @user2057047 The fiddle in this link is almost the same as [the one you posted in your question](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/h6Q38/1/) as source you're changing to ids. The best way to deal with it is using `class` as in code you posted first. My solution is to allow you using `id` if you really need it for some reason. Why did you decide to change it to use ids?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h6Q38/11/ i changed to class now.. but still class does not give the required output

Comment: @user2057047 Isn't this code working as you want - http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/h6Q38/1/ ? If yes, why are you changing anything?

Comment: i changed it as to suit as per my liking but i found that it is nor working in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h6Q38/11/